# Golang equivalent of fitdistrplus in R?

Tags: r, go, math, statistics, fitdistrplus

I'm trying to reproduce fitting a beta distribution in Go, given an input of floating-point rates:

```
rates = [0.20, 0.15, 0.002, 0.017, 0.181, 0.004, ...]
```

[You can do this in R quite easily](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/376638/29018) using `fitdistrplus`, which chooses reasonable starting values automatically, unlike the MASS package which "struggles":

```
x <- c(0.0955104277250779, 0.0782381918284555, 0.109683584625186, 
       0.10115721657354, 0.102377369846524, 0.0691699604743083,
       0.0940254652301665, 0.078494747777906, 0.0824474231569216,
       0.0886513916653852)

fit <- fitdist(x, "beta")
```

I am trying to figure out how to fit a beta distribution in Go though which is proving difficult, finding the right functions (stats isn't my strong suit).

I have heard I can use "method-of-moments" as starting values, but also having them automatically be decided would be nice if it works like that out of the box.